# How to choose these variations of colors from Color panel of illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've always been using this *Color Picker* window, which you see after double clicking Fill/Stroke UI element in Illustrator. It feels easy and flexible to me maybe because I don't know properly how to use other color panel options in Illustrator.
[image]

**What main feature I like in this:**

(The following 2 images will explain my this paragraph). As you see, sometimes I need less shiny/bright color, for example, bright red or bright green doesn't always feel cool in illustrations. So what I do is click on approx. color that I need (The vertical color bar you can see, which has all colors) and then move to left in *Select Color:* option. Here I do what I use most. I move the pointer here and there to adjust brightness/darkness and the *dusty* look of colors, as shown in 2 images. There are N number of directions where you can move it and get the dusty or bright or whatever look of the color.

[image]
[image]

Similarly, I can get any shade of grey color easily:
[image]

Now, I just came to know from my last question that **Color** Panel in Illustrator should be used, instead of this.

Here is the image of that:

[image]

Now, here the 1st step is same. You just click and primary color in the color area. But now, you (I) can't do all the remaining steps, unless you highly brainstorm with those R, G, B scales manually, I guess. Or you select color from some other source and paste the color code into it.

Also, suppose you clicked on red colored area and you want similar dusty red, so you move the picker little below so it gets dark, but there's risk that yellow will also get mixed with it as it is adjacent to it. But actually you want black in it.

Honestly, I'm confident in selecting only Red, Yellow, Green, Light Blue, Blue, Pink, Red, White and Black colors only in **Color** Panel.

For some reasons, I don't use swatches usually. I like *fresh* colors. I hope you got my problem. Is there any solution for it or is there something to explore or some flexibility that I don't know yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>This answer is using Illustrator CS6 screenshots and animations because... to date.. I find that the best version of Illustrator for a few reasons. The panel operations have been the same for a few decades. It's unlikely you'll find the basic panel operations different than what may detailed here.</sub>

---

The *first* thing to do with the **Color Panel** is to `Show Options` if they aren't already displayed. This way you can see color sliders.

[image]

You'll see sliders for whichever color mode the document is currently in, RGB or CMYK....

[image]

---

The **Color Ramp** at the bottom of the panel is there as a general target area. It is *not meant* to be a precise color selector. You can increase the ramp size by increasing the panel size.

[image]

Again, this is just to generally target a color area - blue, red, yellow, etc. not pick a *specific* color. You *can* hold the mouse down as you drag over the ramp and the color will change in a fluid manner.

<sub>(The polarized display of the color ramp in the animations here is due to the gif format (for animation) and dithering. The ramp is always smooth within the application, other than the `Web Safe` ramp. I'm uncertain if *anyone* actually uses "web safe" colors in today's world.)</sub>

---

Once you pick a general area of color from the ramp, you can then use the sliders above the ramp to further target the color you're after.

[image]

---

If you depress the <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key *then* click a slider and drag, you'll find *all* the sliders will move in unison.

For CMYK, A slider will only move in unison if the stop has a value *other than* 0 or 100%. CMYK slider stops "stick" at either 0 or 100% - see the K slider stop in the animation below and how it remains at 0 while other stops move. For RGB documents, slider stops will "stick" at 255, but not "stick" at 0.

[image]

This can be helpful to refine a color without overly altering it's hue.

---

The most useful part of the panel for many are the **HSB** sliders - Hue, Saturation, Brightness.

[image]

This is where you can tweak specific aspects of a color similar to the Color *Picker* options. You can increase/decrease Saturation to add/remove color vibrancy. Increase/Decrease Brightness to lighten/darken a color. Or alter the hue slider to get a different color range.

[image]

<sub>(Note: The Command/Ctrl shortcut trick for slider unison will *not* work on the HSB sliders.)</sub>

The annoying aspect of the Color Panel, at least up to CC2019, has been the inability of the panel to *stick* to HSB. The panel has a tendency to auto-switch back to sliders based upon the document profile (CMYK/RGB). This forces the user to constantly reset the panel to HSB sliders. Users have repeatedly asked for a fix for this, but as of CC2019 there is none.

---

With all this *any* color you want is achievable from the **Color Panel**. There's really little or no need for the OS-driven Color *Picker* in Illustrator. In fact, the Color *Picker* is merely there mostly so users see it when they expect to see it - a way of making Photoshop, Indesign, Corel, Quark, Xara, Freehand, etc. users more comfortable.

There's *nothing* wrong with choosing color from the Color *Picker*. However, often the issue can be the double-click to *open* the Picker, especially on things like Gradient Color Stops. If you prefer to use the Picker, there's no harm in it. But you may need to adjust your inherent desire to double-click to open the *Picker* and instead click an object (or color stop) once, then click/dblclick the color square in the Toolbar or **Color Panel** to bring up the *Picker*.

---

I'll be frank, I've used Illustrator since it's inception (v1.0) and I have never opened the Color *Picker* in Illustrator while working. Not once. I've only ever opened it to take a screenshot of it like I did for this answer. But that's merely *my workflow* and I'm not by any means advocating that *anyone* need work how I work. I simply learned Illustrator and familiarized myself with the **Panel** long before the *Picker* was ever part of Illustrator. However, when I hear or see users expressing "pain points" with the *Color Picker*, my reaction is often to question why they are even bothering with the (unnecessary) *Picker*.

---

<sub>(For clarity, use of the term "Picker" or "Color Picker" above refers to [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WCzt.png) window.)</sub>

Comment: This must be the *full* story about the Color panel.

Comment: This is where I got to with this question as well- Learn how to use the Color Panel or keep using the Color Picker if you prefer- you will just have to learn the quirks of the Color Picker...

Comment: I won't comment right now if it will solve my problem or not. But I'll definitely start trying color panel from now on. Will comment after having experience with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the exact same functionality with the *Color* panel as with the *Color Picker*, but you can click the sandwich menu in the upper right corner and choose *HSB* to get another way of choosing color.

Now you can choose a *hue* (H) and experiment with the *saturation* (S) and *brightness* (B) sliders without changing the *hue*.

If you set *saturation* to *0*, you can use the *brightness* slider to choose between gray tones.

[image]

Comment: I like Photoshop's Color panel as it as same color picker functionality. Can't we change this color area (I mean instead of multiple colors in color area, just single color like color picker area) just like Photoshop?

Comment: Also, how did you change the color area view to textured one?

Comment: No, that's what I answer. You can't get the exact same functionality, but something close. You only have the options available in the sandwich menu. (The textured look comes from the gif having too few colors to show a smooth gradient. )

Comment: lol for the 2nd query.

Comment: Doesn't it look complicated @Wolff the colored area, I mean side by side colors are confusing while picking color, unlike Photoshop color picker. where only one color and its variations are shown.

Comment: I dunno, I don't even really use the lower part. Not very precise. And I seldom have the need for many variations of the same color. You could use other approaches to choose colors. Make images in Photoshop which you pick from in Illustrator for example. Anyway, criticizing Adobe is off-topic isn't it? We can only ask and answer about *how* the programs work - not *why*.

Comment: Am I criticizing? I think I want to know opinions.

Comment: OK, *evaluating* then. But opinions about programs belong in chat. A question needs to be answerable. Q: "Is this possible?", A: "Unfortunately, no".

Comment: Okay Wolff. Let's see what others answer.

Comment: 1 vote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Vikas.

Just learn to use the HSB. HSB is much more understandable, because it is how we experience color. Lets say we have a Ferrari and it is in a shadow.
Hue: the color (red)
Saturation: how much pigment is in the paint (maximum)
Brightness: how much light falls on that paint (50% shadow)

If you don't know why you should use HSB it is frustrating but then you like it. Just think about it, if you have pure white but it is in a shadow, then it is no longer white, it is gray and if it is in a dark room it is black. You can do that with HSB.

Overall I recommend watching "Understanding Color" and "Lighting Mastery" by Blender Guru on YouTube. They are really worth watching!